# How do I alter a string between specific points in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say I want to change the text in between '[code][/code]' and make the text monospace (CSS) Just like Quora does, but only simpler. How would I go about doing this?

For example:

String - "Here is some code: [code]Hello[/code]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way using a RegExp to replace the `[code]` tags with `<pre>` tags:

```
yourString.replace(/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/ig, '<pre>$1</pre>');
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/24jq4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex, something like this:

```
result = subject.replace(/\[code\](.*?)\[\\/code\]/g, "[code]$1 World[/code]");
```

The above will replace "Hello" with "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex:

```
str = str.replace(/(\[code\]).*?(\[\/code\])/, '$1Good Bye$2');
```